ASP.NET Core: ApplicationUser is null on form submission
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application where users can add delivery addresses. The process involves a GET request to display the form and a POST request to handle form submission. Despite initializing ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId in the GET action, these fields are null during the POST request, causing a validation error.
This is the relevant code:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddAddress()
{
    var user = await _um.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "User not found.";
        return RedirectToAction("DisplayDeliveryAddress");
    }

    DeliveryAddress address = new DeliveryAddress
    {
        ApplicationUserId = user.Id,
        ApplicationUser = user
    };

    return View(address);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddAddress(DeliveryAddress addressModel)
{
    var user = await _um.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "User not found.";
        return RedirectToAction("DisplayDeliveryAddress");
    }

    // Reassign the user and user ID to the address model
    addressModel.ApplicationUserId = user.Id;
    addressModel.ApplicationUser = user;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _db.Addresses.Add(addressModel);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            TempData["Success"] = "New delivery address is registered!";
            return RedirectToAction("DisplayDeliveryAddress");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "An error occurred while adding the address.";
            return View(addressModel);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Please correct the errors and try again.";
    }

    return View(addressModel);
}

@model DeliveryAddress

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Address";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">@TempData["Success"]</div>
}

@if (TempData["Error"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">@TempData["Error"]</div>
}

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="country"></label>
        <input asp-for="country" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="country" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Contactname"></label>
        <input asp-for="Contactname" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Contactname" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="phone"></label>
        <input asp-for="phone" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="phone" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="street"></label>
        <input asp-for="street" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="street" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="sted"></label>
        <input asp-for="sted" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="sted" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="city"></label>
        <input asp-for="city" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="city" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="zipCode"></label>
        <input asp-for="zipCode" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="zipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Address</button>
    <a asp-action="DisplayDeliveryAddress" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
</form>

Model:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace OnlineShop.Models
{
    public class DeliveryAddress
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Country/region")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Contact name")]
        public string Contactname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Contact phone number")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Street")]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Post sted")]
        public string Sted { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Zip code")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; } // Foreign key
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } // Reference navigation
    }
}

Despite initializing ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId in the GET action and ensuring these values are set in hidden fields in the form, I'm still getting a validation error in the POST action indicating that the ApplicationUser field is required.
When debugging, I see that ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId are null in the POST action.

The ApplicationUser field is required

What I've tried:

Ensuring the hidden fields for ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId are populated correctly in the view.
Reassigning ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId in the POST action after retrieving the user

Why are ApplicationUser null in the POST action despite being set in the GET action and included as hidden fields in the form? How can I resolve this issue so that these fields retain their values during form submission?

Most likely the user is not logon. The solution is siomple, redirect to login page when the user is not logged in. All u need to do is just add [Authorized] on top of the action.

The user is logged in, it initializes the ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId, but when I want to check if the model is valid or not, the ApplicationUser will be null

Although you initialize ApplicationUser and ApplicationUserId in the GET method but you do not set the value in the view so that the form submit will not submit the corresponding value. Also, resign the value will not influence the model validation result.
From .NET 6 the non-nullable property must be required, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.
To avoid this, the first way is you could simply remove <Nullable>enable</Nullable> from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).
The second way is to initialize the value in the model:
public class DeliveryAddress
{
    //...

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }= string.Empty;
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; } = new ApplicationUser();
}

The third way, you can add ? to allow nullable:
public class DeliveryAddress
{
    //...

    public string? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser? ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}


thank you very much, it solve my problem!
